# Change dateFormat in amChart from yyyy to days as mon, tue

Tags: php, json, amcharts

Am stuck with this date format thing i cant change it or i dont know how? from year to my own written week day which is mon or tue.

am chart code:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
      
   

          <script>
        // Haetan data omasta APistä 
        fetch('https://users.metropolia.fi/~noorja/WSK12021/OTIUM02-offical/OTIUM02/API/hrv.php')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                // Themes begin
                am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
                // Themes end
    
                // Create chart
                var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
                chart.paddingRight = 20;
    
                chart.data = data;
                chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "EEE";
    
                var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
                dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
                dateAxis.baseInterval = {
                    timeUnit: "day",
                    count: 1
                };
    
                var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
                valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    
                var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
                series.dataFields.dateX = "day";
                series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
                series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
                series.strokeWidth = 3;
    
                chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
                chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
                chart.cursor.fullWidthLineX = true;
                chart.cursor.lineX.strokeWidth = 0;
                chart.cursor.lineX.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(2);
                chart.cursor.lineX.fillOpacity = 0.1;
    
                chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
    
            });
    </script>
```

The data file with json format i call it hrv.php:

```
<?php 

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
    
    //Tästä voi käytä tietokanta ja sessioita 
         $data = array(
        array("year"=> "1950",
        "value"=> 3),
        
        array("year"=> "1951",
        "value"=> 4),
        
        array("year"=> "1952",
        "value"=> 3),
        
        array("year"=> "1953",
        "value"=> 2),
        
        array("year"=> "1954",
        "value"=> 5),
        
        array("year"=> "1955",
        "value"=> 2),
        
        array("year"=> "1956",
        "value"=> 4),
        
        array("year"=> "1957",
        "value"=> 1)
         );
         echo(json_encode($data));
         ?>
```

I have tried to ake some sort of EEEE format but is not working it makes it even worst, so what it shoukd be changed so i get in my chart  mon , tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, su ? instead of those years 1950+

[image]

Comment: I am generally confused by this. If you don't want years, then why is it saved by years in your data source?

Comment: well, this is an test or lest say its begining of the process, i litrally dont know how to use it thats why i had to put it all here!

Comment: Alright, I'll ignore the logic behind this. Where is the part of code that tries to do this year-to-day conversion?

Comment: Lets say i dont know how to the hell to do that and i need help actually! i need to change the format but i cant do it because am new at this. i looked up like 20 h and did not found any benfical site or advice to get it that way.                                                                                  Only thing i got hands on is this code to convert the date format, but is not working : even i have changed the json to days and other values!!    this is the code : $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('yyyy', '1950');
    echo $datetime->format('EEE');

Answer (score 0):

Now is working with adding, yy-MM-dd in the chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yy-MM-dd"; .